# extjs4 proxy rest multiple request issue

Tags: rest, extjs4

Hi I am encountering a wierd behavior with my application:when I modify an item and then my proxy doas a put request, the first time is ok, the second time it sends two requests: the first with the data of the previous one, the second one with the actual data, the third time it sends three requests, onmy system it is not a big issue, because at end I get the right value on my database, but on my customer's system the result it is not always correct. Then I would like to remove this behavior.

this is my store:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
        {
            storeId: 'bbCompaniesStore',
            model:'Company',
            pageSize: pageSize,
            proxy:
            {
                idProperty : '_id',
                type: 'rest',
                url: 'data/companies/',
                autoload: true,
                noCache: true,
                sortParam: undefined,
                actionMethods:
                 {
                        create : 'PUT',
                        read   : 'GET',
                        update : 'POST',
                        destroy: 'DELETE'
                    },

                reader:
                {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'total'
                },

            },// proxy
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
                    Ext.gritter.add({
                        title: MongoVision.text['action.' + operation.action] || operation.action,
                        text: (operation.error ? operation.error.statusText : null) || MongoVision.text.exception
                    }); 

                    // Ext JS 4.0 does not handle this exception!
                    switch (operation.action) {
                        case 'create':
                            Ext.each(operation.records, function(record) {
                                record.store.remove(record);
                            });
                            break;

                        case 'destroy':
                            Ext.each(operation.records, function(record) {
                                if (record.removeStore) {
                                    record.removeStore.insert(record.removeIndex, record);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                }
                }
        }
);
```

this is my model:

```
Ext.define('Company',
{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {
            name :  'id',
            type : 'string'
        },
        {
            name :'firm',
            type : 'string',
            allowBlank: false
        },{
            name : 'p'
        },
        {
            name: 'linee'
        },
        {
            name : 'c'
        },
        {
            name : 'data',
            type: 'date'
        },
        {
            name :'note'
        },
        { 
            name :'paese'
        },
        {
            name : 'email'
        },
        {
            name : 'telefono'
        },
        {
            name : 'type'
        },
        {
            name : 'website'
        },
        {
            name : 'session_id'
        },
        {
            name : 'group_id'
        }


],
proxy : {
    type : 'rest',
    url : 'data/companies/'
}

}
);
```

after googling around I found a similar issue for extjs3, with no solution, I think it is strange  that after so long time, there is no yet a solution; it should work now

Comment: How are you persisting the models? Using store.sync()?

Comment: thanks,I  create a model with Ext.ModelManager.create and then model.save, but now I think the problem is connected with Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing that I use for updating, I use rowEditing.cancelEdit() before starting to edit, so I do not know

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller where you are doing the saving?

Comment: Hi my back-end server is Prudence So, some time I have to change the url in my proxy this where I do the save after the edit CompanyGrid.on('edit', function() {
              var company = Ext.ModelManager.create(rec.data, 'Company')
                  company.data.session_id = BB.user.user.session_id
                  var old_url = store.getProxy().url
                   store.getProxy().url = old_url + BB.user.user.id +'/'
                  store.remove(company)
                  company.save()
                  store.getProxy().url = old_url
                  store.load()
                 })

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand why you're removing the new model instance from the store, and then saving it. If you're trying to edit an existing model instance, you should be able to find it in your store, and then use the store's sync() method to persist all store changes. Additionally, if you return the updated model data from the server in the response, you shouldn't have to reload the entire store again, as they store should automatically update the changed model instance with the response data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, resolved it by simply passing 
`batchActions: true` when creating the Proxy. The default behavior for 'rest' proxies is to turn off batching.... (See extjs/src/data/proxy/Rest.js)